# Selenium test execution order chnges when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, debugging, order-of-execution

In Visual Studio 2017, I have a Unit test project. In that project, I have 2 tests in Test Explorer.

When I run these tests the execution order is (Test1, Test2), but when I debug the same tests the execution order is (Test2, Test1).

Why is the execution order changing when I debug the test runs? How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you run your tests for several times? Whether it will have different test results? As far as I know, even if we run them at the same time, but we couldn't really control the test ordered unless we add the delay in one test or add them to the ordered test, the most important issue is that it will load the symbols assembly during debugging mode or others. I think it would impact the debugging performance, maybe you could debug them in release mode, check the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using [OrderedTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx).

Comment: yes, ordered test would be a good solution for it. You could mark it as the answer:)